# redux: dispatch is not working

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am developing a react app with redux 
I wrote my actions in a separate js file as shown below

```
function getCity(city,dispatch) {
  fetch('https://################', {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "user-key": "#############",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  }).then((res) => {
    return res.json()
  }).then((data) => {
    console.log(data.location_suggestions);
    dispatch({type:'getting_cities', city:data.location_suggestions});
  })
}
```

then I mapped them with the code below

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    getLocations:(data) => getCity(data),
    logStore: () => dispatch({type:'LOGSTORE'})
  }
}
```

console.log is working great but dispatch is not working.

please help me

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't enough information to debug. What happens? Any error?

Comment: no errors but dispatch is not storing info in store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the solution is simple:
You forgot to send `dispatch` with `getCity` in the snippet where you are calling your action

```
// Change this
getCity(data)

// To this
getCity(data, dispatch)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check out the redux docs about [Async Actions](https://redux.js.org/advanced/asyncactions) especially the [Async Action Creators section](https://redux.js.org/advanced/asyncactions#async-action-creators).

Try the following:

```
function getCity(city) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return fetch(...)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => dispatch({ ... }));
  }
}
```

You can also use more cool arrow syntax. This is equivalent.

```
function getCity(city) {
  return dispatch => 
    fetch(...)
      .then(...)
      .then(...);
}
```

Don't forget to export your function since it's in a separate file.

Now to dispatch your action creator in your main file:

```
import { getCity } from '...';

store.dispatch(getCity('berlin'));
```

Be sure to use [`connect`](https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact) if you work with React.